# Should I switch to F2FS?

Tags: file-system

I've heard a lot of hype about Samsung's filesystem named Flash-Friendly File System (or F2FS for short). I've heard about cases where the device apparently worked faster after switching to this filesystem, and I've also heard where the filesystem didn't work well and some data got lost.

Should I switch to this filesystem? Are there really objective improvements to device's preformance, or is it just a false positive? Are there any hidden risks?

Comment: if this is have an Stable version, It might be a good idea to test.also see this : `http://www.xda-developers.com/f2fs-put-to-the-test-against-ext4/` and read comments.